# How to fetch high quality instagram picture

Tags: android, user-interface, instagram-api

I have a working android code to fetch instagram photos

```
  JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser
                        .getJSONFromUrlByGet("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token="+ instaaccesstok
                                + "&count="
                                + InstagramApp.TAG_COUNTS);

                System.out.println("jsonObject::" + jsonObject);


                JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

                //    Log.d("shan user", String.valueOf(data));
                String str_url="";
                for (int data_i = 0; data_i < data.length(); data_i++)
                {
                    JSONObject data_obj = data.getJSONObject(data_i);

                    JSONObject images_obj = data_obj
                            .getJSONObject(TAG_IMAGES);

                    JSONObject thumbnail_obj = images_obj
                            .getJSONObject(TAG_THUMBNAIL);





                    instaImageList.add(thumbnail_obj.getString(TAG_URL));

                }
```

But the images, retrieved with this code is not good in quality. How to retrieve, images in various quality.

Comment: Don't use the thumbnail?

Comment: `instaImageList.add(images_obj.getString(TAG_URL));` thumbnails are obviously low quality. use actual image

Comment: Sorry Mohammed, can you please be more specific. Can you please elaborate or tell me what should I use over there.

Comment: you mean "standard_resolution"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso Library to get image from url either it is high quality or lower quality.

First you need to compile `compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"` in your app level **build.gradle** and then use the below code to get image

```
     //Loading Image from URL
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/advertise.png")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   // optional
            .error(R.drawable.error)      // optional
            .resize(768,1280)                        // optional
            .into(imageView);
```